# When Jquery jScrollPane is reinitialized, it goes back to the top. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jquery library jScrollPane to set the custom scroll bar for the whole page.

```
scroll_bar = $('body>div').jScrollPane(
     {
        autoReinitialise: true,
            showArrows: true,
            maintainPosition: false
     }).data('jsp');
```

When new content is added at the bottom of the page (while user is at the bottom of the page), I call:

```
scroll_bar.getContentPane().find(".content").append(some_content);
scroll_bar.reinitialise();
```

This reinitializes the scroll bar, but it takes the user to the top of the page. I would like the window to stay at the same spot. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the data needed, I have no idea if this works, but have you tried:

```
scroll_bar = $('body>div').jScrollPane(
   {
      autoReinitialise: true,
          showArrows: true,
          maintainPosition: false
   });

scroll_bar.data('jsp');
```

And would'nt you normally use the .scroll-pane class for this, and not the body>div selector ?

I would think maybe it should be something like this:

```
var api = scroll_bar.data('jsp');
api.reinitialise();
```

Comment: I think your code and mine are same. I'm just using the chain of functions. I tried yours, but it is not reinitialising...

Comment: It's been some time since I used jScrollPane, but the best person to ask is Kelvin, if you can find him. Try the [Git Pages](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues) or the [contact form](http://www.kelvinluck.com/contact/) on Kelvins site to see if he answers.

Comment: do you know any other similar libraries, which would work inside of iframe?

Comment: There are several, but jScrollPane is probably the most common one. Have a look at [this site](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/11/22/18-customizable-scroll-panes-using-javascript-including-jquery/) for some of the others. I do however not know if they work in an iFrame, or how well they work for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scroll bar to retain its position, you should set the

```
      maintainPosition: true
```

Also, try reconstruct the code like this:

```
            // Use jscrollpane api function to enable reinitialization
            var scrollelement = $('body>div').jScrollPane({ maintainPosition: true});
            var api = scrollelement.data('jsp');
            api.getContentPane().html(result);


            // Needed to apply jscrollpane after change new container type
            api.reinitialise();
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: now it doesn't change the position, but it won't reinitialise it. The height changes since new stuff is being added to the page, but scrollbar won't reinitialize. :(

Comment: are you sure you are using api.getContentPane() to append the result?

Comment: Here's the exact code I'm using: scroll_bar.getContentPane().find(".video[data-msgid~="+msg_id+"] .new_comment").before(template);

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html):

- maintainPosition [boolean] - Whether you want the contents of the scroll pane to maintain it's position when you re-initialise it - so it doesn't scroll as you add more content (default true)

You set it to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For people who have issues re-initializing after the above:

```
function reinitialiseScrollpane() {

        var settings = {
            maintainPosition: true,
            // add your settings here, below are examples
            arrowButtonSpeed: 1,
            showArrows: true,
            animateScroll: true 
        };

    pane.jScrollPane(settings); 
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    api.getContentPane().append();
    api.reinitialise();

}
```

The important part is using the settings. Without re-initialising the settings, it can be glitchy. I have put it in a function call, so you simply call this whenever content is altered in any of your scroll panes (assuming you kept the .scroll-pane class with all regions)